# Performing a Upsert using ReplaceOne, but incrementing one of the fields if the record existed

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am making an upsert in my collectoin, but I want to also increment a counter if the item was already in the collection.

I have this:

```
var user = new User(...);
users.ReplaceOne<User>(
  u => u.Id == user.Id,
  user,
  new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true }
);
```

Say the User object has a field like 'LikeCount'.  I want to increment this value if the record existed, is this possible with an upsert?

Comment: Do you want to just to update 'LikeCount' field or the whole document?

Comment: if it doesn't exist, entire document insert other wise just update counter

Comment: I would suggest you to use update method instead of replace. If you use upsert in update method, in case of no document found in collection, it will insert new document and if it matches to filter, it will update necessary part of the document. So you will not have to replace the entire document but only the necessary part (LikeCount in this case) will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UpdateOne` method and pass in `Upsert=true` but within the update you can set all your document properties using the `SetOnInsert`.

```cs
class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}

var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<User>("users");

var user = new User {Name = "My User", Age = 30};
var id = new ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011");
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
var update = Builders<User>.Update.Inc(x => x.Counter, 1)
    .SetOnInsert(u => u.Name, user.Name)
    .SetOnInsert(u => u.Age, user.Age);

await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, new UpdateOptions{IsUpsert = true});
```